# Run reverse for loop in single line

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, underscore.js, reverse

I want to run a reverse for loop and each item to be passed as a parameter to a function.
I can use `underscore`.

```
var myItems = [1,2,3,4,5];
_.each(myItems, print); //It calls print in sequential order but I want reverse order

function print(value) {
  value = value + 1;
  // Some other modifications
  console.log(value);
}
```

Now, I need to do the same thing but I want to run reverse loop. I know I can write for loop like this

```
for (var i = myItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```

I am looking for concise code..something like `_.reverseLoop` or `myItems.reverse`. 
Is there any other API available in `underscore` or `Array.prototype` to run a loop in reverse and execute callback for each item ?

Comment: _.each(myItems.reverse(), print);

Comment: This could make a nice little open source contribution.

Comment: @wared I was just not aware of `reverse` method..Can happen to anyone.

Comment: @blunderboy "I was just not aware of `reverse`", this is precisely the problem. `reverse` is probably one of the most known method in javacript. All methods in one page here (google "mdn array") : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array. Reading this will save you a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

> The `reverse()` method reverses an array in place. The first array
>   element becomes the last and the last becomes the first.

So you can reverse your array and use:

```
_.each(myItems.reverse(), print)
```

Or

```
_.each(myItems.slice().reverse(), print)
```

Comment: adding slice before reverse will create a shallow copy and keep the initial array unmodified, correct?

Comment: @user2910265 Yes. Just use `array.slice(0).reverse()`. The `0` is of course optional.

Comment: @user2910265 Using `slice` is one option : `Array.apply(Array, array)`.

Comment: @CD.. Thanks It worked for me..I was not aware for `reverse` method in Array prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse a array in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as

```
.reverse()
```

so you can use

```
_.each(myItems.reverse(), print)
```

[**js Bin Example**](http://jsbin.com/ogOCaBow/2/edit)